# How do I use unicode values to create a string of hindi in php?

Tags: php

I want to create a string using the unicode values of devnagari script, I want to use this in a php file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did u tried anything? your code?

Comment: I actually want to use the following code in creating a captcha in devnagari, but i dont think its working as its showing greek characters while its giving the output.

Comment: $letters = 'भबहगदजडपरकतटचमनवलसयघधझढञफऱखथछठशषणज्ञत्रक्षश्र23456789';
 $len = mb_strlen($letters);
 for ($i = 0; $i< 6;$i++) {
     $letter = $letters[rand(0, $len-1)];
     imagestring($image,9 ,  5+($i*30), 20, $letter, $text_color);
     $word.=$letter;
 }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: @AnandSaran Code goes in your question, not comments. Edit your question.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can't safely select a single utf-8 character with `$letters[rand(0, $len-1)];`, since it's a multi-byte encoding: you just get a single byte. You should use `mb_substr` instead.

```
$letter = mb_substr($letters, rand(0, $len-1), 1);
```